How can see what request context looks like for an AWS request?
I was reading some documentations, but could not find a way to see them. I was trying to use Cloudtrail, but it seems like it only shows an event record for the api call performed.
{
"eventVersion": "1.09",
"userIdentity": {
    "type": "AssumedRole",
    ...
    }
},
"eventTime": "2024-11-22T16:52:55Z",
"eventSource": "logs.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "CreateLogStream",
"awsRegion": "us-east-1",
"sourceIPAddress": ...,
"userAgent": ...,
"requestParameters": {
    ...
},
"responseElements": null,
"requestID": "df538....b987-2f...24a",
"eventID": "f3e....9f7-8aaf-e00...3d21",
"readOnly": false,
"eventType": "AwsApiCall",
"apiVersion": "20140328",
"managementEvent": true,
"recipientAccountId": "....",
"eventCategory": "Management",
"tlsDetails": {

    ...
}

}
How can we see the actual request context? e.g. when an lambda function makes a request to download an object in S3. I am hopping to see the request context，so I can debug the condition section of my policy by seeing what keys are present.

Did you check on S3 events instead (PutObject or GetObject)?

CloudTrail is primarily designed to log AWS API calls and events, not the payload or the full request context. To capture the full context or actual content of requests (e.g., a Lambda function downloading an S3 object), you need to use additional configuration.
1 - You can enable S3 Access Logs
2 - Use Lambda’s Logging Mechanisms
logging.info(f"Downloaded object {object_key} from {bucket_name}")
logging.info(f"Response metadata: {response['ResponseMetadata']}")

3 - Enable S3 Object-Level CloudTrail Data Events
These methods, used in combination, will give you a comprehensive view of the actual requests and their contexts. Let me know if you need help implementing any of these!
